# How to display the currently running function in the echo area?

Tags: echo-area, message

I have this function:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)

  (call-interactively 'bar)
  (call-interactively 'baz)
  (call-interactively 'qux)
  (call-interactively 'quux)
  (call-interactively 'fred))
```

When I call `foo`, I would like to see in the echo area a message like `X is running` as long as the `X` function is running, where `X` is `bar`, `baz` and so on, but without hiding any messages that emacs might show when `foo` itself is running. I mean something like this:

```
bar is running
Query replacing regexp foo with bar: (? for help)
```

Just I have no idea how to do such a thing.

---

**Clarification**

db84x pointed out to me that my question is unclear, so I'm going to clarify it.

Suppose `bar` contains this line:

```
(query-replace-regexp "bar" "qwerty" nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

When emacs finds this line, the following will appear in your echo area:

```
--- Echo area ---
Query replacing regexp bar with qwerty: (? for help)
--- Echo area ---
```

When I call `bar`, I first want a message to appear in echo area:

```
--- Echo area ---
bar is running
--- Echo area ---
```

and this message must not disapper as long as `bar` is running. So, when emacs finds the `query-replace-regexp`above, the echo area should appear this way:

```
--- Echo area ---
bar is running
Query replacing regexp bar with qwerty: (? for help)
--- Echo area ---
```

I'm sorry if my question was unclear. Hope now it is.

---

**Attempt 1**

I picked up Drew's suggestion about `message` and I found `with-temp-message`:

> Macro: with-temp-message message &rest body
>
> This construct displays a message in the echo area temporarily, during the execution of body. It displays message, executes body, then
> returns the value of the last body form while restoring the previous
> echo area contents.

It seems this macro is just what I am looking for, so I defined this function:

```
(defun fred ()
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-message
      (message "Time's up! Three bucks off!")
    (query-replace-regexp "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))))
```

When I call `fred`, my message is shown only at the end of its execution and not during. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Add calls to `message` in your command, or advise those commands you invoke, to have them add calls to `message`. (But this hints at an X-Y problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that we’ve discovered that you actually want to display *two* messages, your own message plus whatever the code you are running wants to display, we may be able to answer the question.

I think you could potentially do what you want by changing the `set-message-function` variable temporarily. I don’t have time to verify that this will work, but something like this might work:

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((prefix "")
         (set-message-function
          (lambda (message)
            (concat prefix "\n" message))))
    (setq prefix "bar is running")
    (call-interactively 'bar)
    (setq prefix "baz is running")
    (call-interactively 'baz)
    (setq prefix "qux is running")
    (call-interactively 'qux)
    (setq prefix "quux is running")
    (call-interactively 'quux)
    (setq prefix "fred is running")
    (call-interactively 'fred)))
```

Check out [39.4.1 Displaying Messages in the Echo Area](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Messages.html) in the Emacs Lisp manual for more information. You can also open the Emacs manuals inside of Emacs with `C-h i`.

Comment: @db84x I've already tried as you say, but it doesn't work: without the macro `message` no message is displayed in the echo area. Instead, using the `message` macro, my message is displayed in the echo area after `fred` has been run and the message does not disappear as I think it should. I guess I'm not understanding the meaning of `with-temp-message`, aren't I?

Comment: Works for me. Test it with something that doesn’t itself replace the message, like this: `(with-temp-message "Time's up! Three bucks off!" (sleep-for 1))`

Comment: @db84x Thanks, this last code works for me too, just the message does not remain in the echo area: it appears for a while and gives way to "Query replacing ...", while I want it to always remain visible as long as `fred` is running. This way you should see in the echo area "Time's up! ..." and under it "Query replacing ..." or whatever message emacs might show.

Comment: Oh, you want to somehow display _multiple_ messages? You never said anything about that in your question.

Comment: @db84x I said "as long as the `X` function is running". I thought it was clear what I meant. I'm sorry it wasn't.

Comment: @db84x Tested. It works fine, thank you.